# How to fill missing field with data to existing documents in mongo db?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have documents like

```
   [{ _id:.., mailTitle:"hello", broadcastMessage:"how are u"}]
   [{ _id:.., mailTitle:"hello john", broadcastMessage:"how are u john"}]
   [{ _id:.., mailTitle:"hello", broadcastMessage:"how are u john",
   user_id:"1", dateSent:"12/12/2016"
   }]
```

Now I want to add  user_id:"1", dateSent:"12/12/2016" to first two and all the others documents.

Please help!!!

Comment: So us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using [update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) (deprecated) :**

```
 db.collection.update(
           { "user_id": {$exists: false}, "dateSent": {$exists: false} },
           { $set:
              {
                user_id : 1,
                dateSent: "12/12/2016", (Use a UTC Date object instead of string)
              }
           },
        {
            multi: true
        }
    );
```

**Using [updateMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/)** :

```
db.collection.updateMany(
      { "user_id": {$exists: false}, "dateSent": {$exists: false} },
      { $set:
              {
                user_id : 1,
                dateSent: "12/12/2016", (Use a UTC Date object instead of string)
              }
      }
   );
```

The above will pick up all those documents that don't have a field called `user_id` and `dateSent`, and then set those fields. Hope this helps.